# Why will a child property not update when databinding in XAML

Tags: xaml, data-binding

Can someone explain to me why the first property below (Name) updates fine from the UI, but the second one (End) does not?  Both properties display correctly, so it IS bound.  It just won't update the child property.

Period.Period (not my choice in the naming) is defined as a datetimeoffset.

```
<custom:FieldControl TargetObject="{Binding Path=Period}" TargetProperty="Name" IsReadOnly="False" />
<custom:FieldControl TargetObject="{Binding Path=Period.Period}" TargetProperty="End" IsReadOnly="False" />
```

I'm very new to XAML, so, if I haven't included enough detail, let me know and I'll edit the question.

Comment: FYI, the issue was that I was using an immutable object.

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to implement a [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Here is an example with your two properties:

```
public class PeriodSample : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    private DateTimeOffset period;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
        }
    }

    public DateTimeOffset Period
    {
        get
        {
            return period;
        }
        set
        {
            period = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Period));
        }
    }

    public PeriodSample()
    {
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

This concept allow to notify the Control when the binded properties changed.

If that doesn't solve the problem, could you provide a more complete example please?

Comment: No problem ! Please let me know if this solved your problem.